# Change the title of groub column in kendo mvc grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a grid , and i am grouping the data on date column like this :

```
            .Group(g => g.Add(c => c.EmployeeId)).Group(g => g.Add(c => c.CheckInTime.Day))
```

and it works fine, but the problem is the title is CheckInTime.Day .
my question is how can i change this title ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have the CheckinTime.Day defined as a Bound column on the grid?

Comment: No , I have CheckinTime as Date column in the grid ,but i want to make the group on CheckinTime.Day

Comment: I came across this issue a while back. I was able to use a column and have that grouped. My requirements prevented allowing the user to change the grouping so it worked out for me. I added some of the things I tried below, however, I think the group title will fallback to the FieldName when there is no bound column present.

Comment: Actually i added the column as bounded column in the grid,and I set the column.Visible(false) and this do the trick

Comment: Will update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a column field that matches the group field then you can set the bound fields Title to whatever you want to display. However, I don't think you can have a different title for the column and group header.

```
columns.Bound(c => c.CheckInTime.Day).Width(100).Title("This will in column header and group header");
```

If you do not have a bound column that matches a group field then you might be able to get away with something like:

```
columns.Bound(c => c.CheckInTime.Day).Title("Group Title")
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "visibility:hidden;" })
        .HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "visibility:hidden;" })
        .ClientGroupFooterTemplate(new { style = "visibility:hidden;" })
        .FooterHtmlAttributes(new { style = "visibility:hidden;" })
```

However, using the above hack adds a ui inconsistency on the first column. There may be a more elegant way to have a group field without a bound column display a different title using js, have not found it yet.